# Angularjs. Resource has value in service but doesn't return data to controller

Tags: angularjs, promise, resources

I'm trying to get data from rest service with $resource anda in my service data return has value but when I try to get it in my controller js class this one daesn't has value. And I can't to go into if because I dont have value in my result.

> controller.js

```
 AsignaturaProfesor.checkAsignaturainProfesor({asignaturaId: vm.miAsignatura.id, profesorId: vm.miProfesor.id}, function (result){

            console.log ("result", result); 
            if (result === 1){
               console.log("Result is true");
            {
 });
```

> service.js

```
    'checkAsignaturainProfesor': { 
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/asignaturaprofesors/checkAsignaturainProfesor/:asignaturaId/:profesorId',
        transformResponse: function (data){
            if (data){
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
            }
            console.log('service checkAsignaturainProfesor ',data);
            return data;
```

> inspector console
>   [image]

}

Comment: you should return promise from `service.js` and use `.then()` inside `controller`.

Comment: return data.promise in service.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why that wasn't working.

```
'checkAsignaturainProfesor': { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'api/asignaturaprofesors/checkAsignaturainProfesor/:asignaturaId/:profesorId',
    transformResponse: function (data){
        ***if (data){
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
        }***
        console.log('service checkAsignaturainProfesor ',data);
        return data;
```

}

the if data souldn't be there. Now I have only server answer in the service.

```
    'checkAsignaturainProfesor': { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'api/asignaturaprofesors/checkAsignaturainProfesor/:asignaturaId/:profesorId',
    transformResponse: function (data){
        console.log('service checkAsignaturainProfesor ',data);
        return data;
```

}